# Unity google VR orientation is skewed on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm just importing unity google VR code to iOS. 
All modules is working fine but VR orientation is not working properly.
It's become little bit skew, when ever VR application in opened in other orientation except cardboard mode (orientation).

Please help me to solve this problem.[image: Image Reference]

Comment: First try to calibrate your vr environment correctly with VR Calibration app, the app will generate (and you can tweak the values to get result you want) and then go to [here](https://wwgc.firebaseapp.com) to generate your qr. Lastly to use your custom qr, click on settings icon and scan your custom code. If that didn't helps try to change some resolution settings in Player > Other.